# PyQt5 QPropertyAnimation finished() how to connect

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In essence, i'm trying to close a window after the animation completes.
In all the documentation and examples i've looked at, they are either in:

- C++
- vague "method definitions"
- Old style slots and connectors

how do i access the finished() that gets 'supposedly' called when the animation finishes?

```
self.anim = QtCore.QPropertyAnimation(window, b"windowOpacity"
self.anim.setStartValue(1)
self.anim.setEndValue(0)
self.anim.setDuration(3000)
#self.anim.finished.connect() does not exist
#QtCore.QObject.connect(stuff) is deprecated
#self.anim.finished(window.destroy) destroys window immediately
```

in all the examples i am reading, they use the first commented out method, but the compiler complains about 'finished' not having a 'connect()' method

Answer (score 6):

I was using `finished` wrong, here's how it should be used:

```
self.anim.finished.connect(self.someMethod)
def someMethod(self):
window.destroy
```

I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: it helped!
pyside6